# Upload multiple folder

Tags: javascript, html

I want to upload multiple folder( folder and its sub folder) using javascript.  Now I am able to upload a single folder which contain more than one files using this code

```
<input style="margin-left:3%;" type="file"  class="width-75" name="docfile[]" id="docFile" onchange="getSelectedFiles(event)" webkitdirectory>
```

But how can I upload multiple folder at a time? Is it possible? Or what changes are made into this code to make it possible? Anybody please help me..

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `multiple` at the end of the input tag like this `<input type="file" multiple>`

Answer (score 0):

Select multiple folders in your Finder (macOS) or File Explorer (Windows) using the Command key on mac or the Ctrl key on windows and upload that.

Comment: IMHO, the OPs question was about how to enable multi-folder upload in his HTML, not how to do this within his Browser or OS.